# Can we create a delta table linked to multiple buckets based on partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, delta-lake, google-cloud-storage

Let's say I want to create a delta table giving a particular location(a gcs bucket) , but I want to load create partitions in a different gcs bucket , lets say table is partitioned on country ,now use case is:
country ='IND' -- a different bucket
country ='US' -- a different bucket , etc and so on..
how can we design a delta table in such a way?

In hive we can create partitions in different locations but how to achieve the same in delta.?

I tried creating a table and altering table , adding partitions in different bucket locations , but that is not working in delta.

Comment: What if we try to filter the df based on the country, and write to diff buckets from there?